# Application UI hangs due to networking , iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, push-notification

I am developing an iOS application where i am implementing push notifications.

In the `AppDelegate` and more specifically in the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` function , after i register for push notifications , i make an http post request to send to my server the users credentials (cfuuid , os , etc..) and the push token.

When the server is app everything goes smoothly. *However* , if for any reason the server is unreachable the UI of the application hangs for around 30 seconds (till the connection timeOut) and the only thing i see is a white screen.

How could i separate the "networking" from the UI ? I guess the answer is by using another thread.

How exactly could i do that ? The only thing i am doing inside the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is use ASIHTTPRequest library to send the credentials to the server.

The code that needs to be executed in the different thread looks like this :

```
NSString *jsonString;
    //jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"deviceUUID\":\"%@\",\"os\":\"ios\", \"active\":\"%d\", \"pushToken\":\"%@\"}",deviceUUID,active,token];
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"deviceUUID\":\"%@\",\"os\":\"ios\", \"pushToken\":\"%@\"}",deviceUUID,token];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);

    //NSString *urlStr= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:CITYINFO_SERVER_URL,@"push_notifications/register"];
    NSString *urlStr= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:CITYINFO_SERVER_URL,@"register.php"];

    //send json file , using ASIHttpClass
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.timeOutSeconds = TIME_OUT_SECONDS;
    [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];

    //NSString *credentials= [self encodeCredentials];
    //[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Basic %@",credentials]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];


    [request appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request startSynchronous];

    if([request responseStatusCode]==200){
        NSLog(@"Server reached. Response Status : 200");
        return true;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Server could not be reached");
        return false;
```

Comment: try [request startAsynchronous]; instead of [request startSynchronous];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending a **synchronous** request just send **Asynchronous** request

```
[request startAsynchronous];
```

And call the method which is hitting service after some time interval from delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

```
[request startSynchronous];
```

***Never. Do. Synchronous. Networking. On the main thread.***

---

Move it to another thread, or even better, make the request async.

Answer (score 0):

use `[request startAsynchronous];`

instead of `[request startSynchronous];`

Answer (score 0):

I think , you are use main thread for send  device token to server,please use the secondary thread for this functionality

try this code :-

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(pushNotifictionJson) withObject:nil];



-(void) pushNotifictionJson
{
    NSString *jsonString;
    //jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"deviceUUID\":\"%@\",\"os\":\"ios\", \"active\":\"%d\", \"pushToken\":\"%@\"}",deviceUUID,active,token];
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"deviceUUID\":\"%@\",\"os\":\"ios\", \"pushToken\":\"%@\"}",deviceUUID,token];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);

    //NSString *urlStr= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:CITYINFO_SERVER_URL,@"push_notifications/register"];
    NSString *urlStr= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:CITYINFO_SERVER_URL,@"register.php"];

    //send json file , using ASIHttpClass
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.timeOutSeconds = TIME_OUT_SECONDS;
    [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];

    //NSString *credentials= [self encodeCredentials];
    //[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Basic %@",credentials]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];


    [request appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request startSynchronous];

    if([request responseStatusCode]==200){
        NSLog(@"Server reached. Response Status : 200");
        return true;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Server could not be reached");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and second method

```
use [request startAsynchronous];

instead of [request startSynchronous];
```